# problems understanding biscuit auth block division

Tags: authorization

I am reallly sorry for making a question here but I couldn't find any other place for this (please forgive me and point me to the right direction in case there is one  ).

I am having a hard time understanding why my biscuit gives positive matches when placed in the `Authority block` but negative ones when  put in a subsequent one despite generating the same facts (picture attached)
[image]

can anyone suggest me why this is the case?

p.s. this is the content of my biscuit:

```
role("admin", ["card:read", "card:write"]);
role("buyer", ["card:read"]);


right($operation) <-
operation($operation),
user($user_id, $user_role),
card_owner($user_id, $card_id),
card($card_id),
$operation == "card:write";

right($operation) <-
user($user_id, $role),
operation($operation),
role($role, $permissions),
$permissions.contains($operation);

operation("card:write");
user("foo", "admin");
card("my-card-id");
```

and my policy:

```
allow if right($op), operation($op);
```

it tried the online tool but I don't understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the most important thing you need to understand about biscuits, is that only the authority block is signed by the root key pair.
The blocks that come after can be added by anyone who holds the token, without having to know the root key pair.
So facts that are not in the authority block are not considered during authorization (unless attenuation blocks carry an external signature AND the authorization logic explicitly references the public key part of the key pair that signed them).
In the common use case, attenuation blocks are there to attenuate the scope of the authority block, and do so by adding checks.
You can still define facts in attenuation blocks, but they will only be considered by the facts defined in the same block.
The documentation covers this in a bit more detail: https://doc.biscuitsec.org/getting-started/authorization-policies.html#blocks